# What is a Parabolic Fixed Point?

Tags: soft-question, dynamical-systems

I know the definitions of hyperbolic and elliptic fixed point (or equilibrium).
However, when I google I find references to 'parabolic elliptic points' but not a proper definition.

Answer (score 1):

Especially for Möbius transformations, you have three types of transformations:

- hyperbolic: one fixed point is stable, one is unstable.
- parabolic: there is one fixed point which is not stable nor unstable.
- elliptic: the fixed point is indifferent.

In general, parabolic fixed points are such that all trajectories converge to the fixed point, but points in a neighborhood eventually quit the neighborhood.

For example, the map $f(z) = \frac{(2+i)x + 1}{x+(2-i)}$ fixes the unit complex circle. It has a fixed point $i$, and it moves all points but $i$ counter-clockwise. Therefore any point of the unit circle is eventually moved close to $i$, but points that start close to $i$ get far away before getting close. That's why it's not a stable fixed point.

Answer (score 1):

In case of discrete dynamical system  fixed point is rationally indifferent or parabolic if it's multiplier of map  at fixed point is a root of unity, see :

- Milnor's book "Dynamic in one complex variable"
- [wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periodic_points_of_complex_quadratic_mappings#Stability_of_periodic_points_.28orbit.29_-_multiplier)

HTH